# Jazzy 0.7.0 XCode 7.3.1 --exclude is not working

Tags: xcode, jazzy

Just wondering if anyone has found a work around for this.  Using --exclude using a full file path to a swift file and Jazzy still includes this file / class in the documentation.  Shell file looks like this

```
jazzy \
--clean \
--author "Author" \
--copyright "Copyright" \
--xcodebuild-arguments '-project,jazzytest.xcodeproj,-scheme,jazzytest' \
--exclude /Users/<username-here>/desktop/jazzytest/jazzytest/source/swift1.swift \
--min-acl public
```

Comment: Turns out had to make a change in how Jazzy is processing the --exclude.  Am working with it now and might put in a PR on the project later.  With this change can specify a relative directory with * and will exclude everything from the directory.

Comment: ort11 did you get this working. If yes, can you stare how please.